# Mobile phone connection in Macedonia for short visit

Tags: cellphones, internet, mobile-operators, macedonia

I will visit Skopje, Macedonia for a week and I would need a mobile phone to call people, but mainly for internet. I have a Three mobile prepaid connection in Ireland. As per the Three website it seems that the roaming charges in Macedonia would be very high. Therefore I would like to know the following:

- What connection for this short visit would be good? I have heard about the VIP, ONE (which have possibly merged now) and T-Mobile.
- Is there any place at the Skopje airport from where I can buy a phone SIM card?
- What documents (or their copies) are needed to get the phone card and the connection?
- How long does it take to get a new connection activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got a [T-Mobile](https://www.telekom.mk/) SIM card at a shop in the arrivals hall at Skopje airport for around € 10 (August 2017). I can't recall the exact plan but it worked well for our short visit (3 days) and the mobile connection was good at the places we visited (Skopje, Mavrovo, Ohrid).

You need to bring your passport and the card is activated pretty much right away.

You might want to check the [Prepaid Data SIM Card Wiki entry for Macedonia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Macedonia) to figure out which plan works best for you. The other carriers are [vip](https://www.vip.mk/) and [Lycamobile](http://www.lycamobile.mk) which are cheaper. All company websites have an English version too.

Skopje airport also has free wifi if you need to do some research before you get your mobile data.

Comment: There is a small hint for people who want to pay less. You can order for €5-8 SIM card on 1Gb, not on 5Gb (€ 10) and use pre-downloaded offline version of Maps.me
Based on my personal experience, there is no huge need into the internet and Google Maps pretty useless in many cases.